# Converting String to Proper/Title Case in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How would I covert a given string to proper/title case using Google Apps Script? I have tried various javascript examples, but cannot seem to make it work.

Comment: Please show what you have so that answerers have something to work with.

Comment: Do it using the javascript String methods. is not specific to apps script.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I found in the [Google Docs](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/kGTkuFfYlas/DxTbgezZyTIJ) help:

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Capitalize', 'proper')
    .addToUi();
}


function proper() {
    var arr = [],
        s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        s.getRange('A2:A')
            .getValues()
            .forEach(function (r) {
                if (r[0]) arr.push([toTitleCase(r[0])])
            });
    s.getRange(2, 2, arr.length, arr[0].length)
        .setValues(arr);
}

function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0)
            .toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1)
            .toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some experimentation and this works

```
var final = "proper title please";
var tempindex = 0;
var tempchar = new Array();
function capitalize()
{
tempchar=final.split("");
tempchar[tempindex]=tempchar[tempindex].toUpperCase();
final=tempchar.join("");
tempindex = final.indexOf(" ", tempindex)+1;
if (final.search(/ [a-z]/) != -1) {
capitalize();
} else {
return final;
}
}
capitalize();
```